# Android Studio - Using AsyncTask to preload custom dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, dialog

I have a custom dialog box that contains many elements to load on it. When prompted to display on first load, it takes 2-3 seconds to load. Each subsequent time I load it, it is nearly instantaneous. I want to have that instantaneous load the first time I go to display the dialog.

With my limited research, I feel that utilizing AsyncTask is the suitable approach (via preloading). Though I am not sure exactly how to implement this. My idea, to preload the dialog, is to load it using the background thread and immediately `hide()` the dialog. Then `onClick`, it will `show()` the dialog. I’ve done the following:

I globally declare: `Dialog dialogFake;`

Under `onCreate` I call the method `startAsyncTask();`

Then on one of my buttons `onClick`, I `dialogFake.show();`

I have added the following code to the end of my MainActivity.class

```
public void startAsyncTask() {
    MainActivity.MyAsyncTask task = new MainActivity.MyAsyncTask(this);
    task.execute();
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {


    MyAsyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

        dialogFake.hide();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialogFake.hide();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialogFake = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogFake.setContentView(R.layout.list);
        dialogFake.setTitle("Title...");
        dialogFake.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialogFake.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        ImageView dialogPicture1 = (ImageView) dialogFake.findViewById(R.id.Picture1);
        TextView dialogTextLabel1 = (TextView) dialogFake.findViewById(R.id.Label1);
        //^More of these... removed for readability
        dialogFake.hide();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        dialogFake.hide();
    }
```

The dialog displays, though the performance isn’t changing… I have yet to specify specific values to each element on the dialog, though the performance is already tanking due to the sheer volume of elements needed to load.

*EDIT*

Help me to understand, maybe I’m going about this the wrong way or trying to accomplish something that’s not possible. The `doInBackground()` is the only method in AsyncTask that offloads processing from the UI thread, thus alleviating hang time, correct?

Also, the `doInBackground()` method does not handle GUI elements, as those are handled by the UI thread, correct?

So, without using AsyncTask, I load the custom dialog without any specific values, just default values (width, height, margins, etc...) as specified in the customlayout xml file. I load the dialog and elements in `onCreate()`, then at the end I `hide()` the dialog. I `show()` via button `onClick()`. What I don’t understand is that the 2-3 delay in loading is still there. I can only assume, that since the `dialogFake.show()` method is the only thing being called when I click the button, is that the delay is from rendering the dialog to the screen… so can AsyncTask “prerender” something so that when `show()` called it is ready to go?

Comment: `onPreExecute()` runs on the UI thread. You'll want to do your work inside the `doInBackground()` method